# Sending e-mails from the dotted version of my Gmail address

Tags: gmail

I am locked out of one of my accounts due to the fact that I had subscribed with the dotted version of my Gmail address, and now I can't send verification e-mails they except from that very address. I added the dotted version in the settings both as and not as an alias, made it default sending address, deliberately chose it while sending an e-mail, with no luck.

How can we send an email from the dotted version, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to send an e-mail from the dotted version of my address, thanks to Thunderbird. Apparently, we can simply add a dot character to the address specified in Thunderbird configuration, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manual-account-configuration, and that works.

PS: I will not accept my answer for now, to see if there are better answers that lets me to do this directly on Gmail interface.

PSS: I even tried the https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html, with no luck.

Comment: Accepting the answer as it's been a while.